# Rails 3.2 Engines - routes not working in test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, functional-testing, rails-engines, rails-admin

I mounted in my app the [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) engine ( according to the instructions from the wiki ) using

> mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/backend', :as => 'rails_admin'

I had to extend one controller from the engine to add a before_filter.
When running my app in development, my extension and the other engine features are working perfectly.

However I have an issue in writing **functional tests using Test::Unit** for my before_filter.
The filter kicks in at the right moment and works as expected, but once the action "tweaked" by the before filter redirects to index ( which is an expected result ), I get the following routing error:

> ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"rails_admin/main"}

The code leading to the exception lies in the engine's method to redirect to index or to the previous page ( kind of referer ); here is the code for the method

> def back_or_index
>
> > if   params[:return_to].presence
> >
> > > params[:return_to]
> >
> > else
> >
> > > index_path
>
> end

I discovered that when running the app in development, the url_for call triggered by index_path is supplied with the proper **path_segments ( i.e.: :model_name => 'user' )** so that the route below is matched

> ```
>    index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
> ```

On the other hand, when running the tests, the path_segments are not supplied, thus the **:model_name** constraint is not satisfied when looking for a matching route.

Since I'm new to engines, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

To me it looks as if the engine should take into consideration the fact that is mounted generating the index_path, but as I said I'm not an expert in this....

Comment: Did you try using the ````use_route```` method in your controller spec call? Here's an example from an engine I worked on . https://github.com/twinge/questionnaire_engine/blob/engine/spec/controllers/answer_pages_controller_spec.rb

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I had already figured out this, but thank you!

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use_route** was not enough: the call to **index_path** was failing anyway.

After lots of debugging, I am not yet completely sure about the root cause of why the same code was not working both in *test* and *development*.

What I observed is that **index_path** in *development* is able to infer the **model_name** from the url of the request, while in *test* is is not.

Although ugly, my solution was to override the method as follows in  app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb

```
module RailsAdmin
 class MainController

        # Override to fix a routing error when running tests
    def back_or_index
      if params[:return_to].presence && params[:return_to].include?(request.host) && (params[:return_to] != request.fullpath)
        params[:return_to]
      else
        # forward :model_name as default_url_options is not aware of it in tests
        index_path( :model_name => params[:model_name] )
      end
    end

 end
end
```

In my controller specs for MainController I do the following

```
put :edit, { :model_name => 'user', :id => root.id, :user => { :role => :root }, :use_route => :rails_admin }
```

And this is what I have in my routes

```
  devise_for :users
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/backend', :as => 'rails_admin'
  mount Rich::Engine => '/rich', :as => 'rich'
```

If anyone has a better solution, sharing would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it and answered in another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75616634/14800616)

Plain link https://stackoverflow.com/a/75616634/14800616