# rails_admin no route matches '/admin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have this in my routes file (at the top):

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

Rails_admin **was working**, yet now rake routes shows:

```
Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

The only thing I've done since restarting the server is add a custom action, which I've since removed, yet still receiving this very strange error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turned out to be a bit weird
I created a new view and in the view did `self.methods`
got a big list with helpers, then saw `rails_admin`, I
did as you have

```rb
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

then checked `rails_admin.methods`
and found `rails_admin.edit_path`, which did work as in routes:

```
Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
      dashboard GET    /                                      
    ...
      edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)
```

So in my case
`rails_admin.edit_path(model_name: 'order', id: 12)`
worked!

Answer: its **rails_admin.*_path**

where * is `show`, `edit`, `delete`, `new`, `index` etc.

Be sure to do in `routes.rb`: the  `as: 'rails_admin'`

```rb
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/', as: 'rails_admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not as strange as you think.  If the original route to the RailsAdmin engine was /admin, there is almost surely some code somewhere requests a path using that syntax.  Something like admin_xxx_xxx_path or admin_xxx_xxx_url.  The Rails url helpers would try to interpret this as /admin/xxx/xxx and the routing error would return with 'rails_admin no route matches '/admin'.