# Rails Engine (4.0.2) routing methods fail in controllers using MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rails-routing, rails-engines

I am able to successfully call actions in my engine controllers from my ActionController::TestCase derived test with:

```
test "should get new" do
  get :new, {'form_id' => '1-2', use_route: :engine_controllers}
  assert_response :success
  assert_match(/Hello World/, @response.body)
end
```

But I am getting an error when referencing a routing method within the controller or view.  Specifically, from the following routes:

```
    Routes for FormEngine::Engine:
            GET  /:form_id(.:format)         form_engine/submissions#new
submissions POST /:form_id(.:format)         form_engine/submissions#create
            POST /payment_info/:id(.:format) form_engine/submissions#update
 submission GET  /submissions/:id(.:format)  form_engine/submissions#show
```

These are intentionally not restful routes.

When I reference `submissions_path` or `form_engine.submissions_path` I get the following error in my test run:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:controller=>"form_engine/submissions", :action=>"create"} missing required keys: [:form_id]
```

I do not get this error when running the server.  I get the path expected: `/form_engine/1-2`

I have traced the problem down to the fact that when run as a server `request.path_parameters` has the `:form_id` in it, but in the test case run `request.path_parameters` is empty.

In a non-engine controller test case, `request.path_parameters` correctly has the path parameters.  From what I can tell, in

```
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:189:
extra_keys = routes.extra_keys(parameters)
```

ends up listing all of the parameters as extra keys and get added to non_path_parameters.  I have not figured out what is misfiring in routes.extra_keys so that :form_id is being listed as an extra key.

I'm guessing that routes is losing the `use_route` or something like that.

I found a somewhat similar question, but I'm not sure it is actually related:
[Rails 3.2 Engines - routes not working in test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281505/rails-3-2-engines-routes-not-working-in-test-cases). So far there hasn't been a satisfactory answer to it.

If anyone can see an obvious mistake I am making or knows of a workaround, I would love to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No answer yet, but I'm in the same place. (RSpec appears to work in this scenario, based on other projects/examples.)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution (for me) in the [Ruby on Rails Engine Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#functional-tests)

```
module MyEngineName
  class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    setup do
      @routes = Engine.routes
    end

    def test_index
      get :index
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would have helped you, but the solution for me (Rails 4.1.8) seemed to have been `use_route`, as you mentioned:

```
# my_controller_test.rb
module MyModule
  class BlahControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    test "gets index" do
      get :index, use_route: 'my_module'
    end
  end
end
```

From:

[Multiple Rails engine rspec controller test not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230932/multiple-rails-engine-rspec-controller-test-not-work)

Much happy.